# Recreate Ionic3 button with Ionic5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic5

How can I recreate an ionic5 button that would look like defined in my old ionic3 app syntax.

```
<button ion-button color="light" clear (click)="foo()">
      TEXT {{bar}}&nbsp;
      <ion-icon name="md-arrow-round-up" large></ion-icon>
</button>
```

If I copy paste this code into my ionic5 app the button would be not formatted but just plain white the default browser button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
<ion-button color="light" fill="clear" (click)="foo()">
    TEXT {{bar}}&nbsp;
    <ion-icon mode="md" name="arrow-up" size="large"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

You can see the new docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components).